# How to include JS objects in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, web

I have this code from my JS File:

```
var formStr = "<h5>How many books?:</h5><input type='number' id='bookinput'
value='' /><input type='button' value='submit' onclick='addbook();' />"
infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
infowindow.setContent(formStr);
infowindow.setPosition(location);
infowindow.open(map);
```

JS variable formStr has html code as you can see above. I want to be able to put JS variables into this without moving the HTML out of my JS file.
Something like:

```
var objectType='book';
var formStr = "<h5>How many *objectType*?:</h5><input type='number' id='bookinput' value='' /><input type='button' value='submit' onclick='addbook();' />"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just concatenate. `var formStr = "<h5>How many " + objectType + "?:</h5>"` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple. Using your example:

```
var objectType='book';
var formStr = "<h5>How many " + objectType + "?:</h5><input type='number' id='bookinput' value='' /><input type='button' value='submit' onclick='addbook();' />"
```

Answer (score 1):

--> Replace :

```
formStr.replace("*objectType*", "books")
```

--> ES5 concatenation : see other answers

--> ES6 string interpolation :

```
let formStr = `<h5>How many ${objectType}?:</h5>`
```